# Registration form using AlertDialog is not showing buttons

Tags: android, forms, button, android-alertdialog

I am trying to create a register form using AlertDialog and Layout Inflater. But the PositiveButton and NegativeButton are not showing, but if I comment the `form.setView(register_layout);`, it becomes a simple dialog and the buttons are showed.

This is how it looks.

[image: Registration form]

I believe it is **not** a color problem from style.xml. Because when I am not using `form.setView(register_layout);` it becomes a simple dialog and the buttons are showed.
[image]

```
private void showRegisterForm(){

    AlertDialog.Builder form = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    form.setTitle("REGISTER");
    form.setMessage("Register with email");

    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
    View register_layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.register_form,null);

    final MaterialEditText editEmail = (MaterialEditText) register_layout.findViewById(R.id.editEmail);
    final MaterialEditText editName = (MaterialEditText) register_layout.findViewById(R.id.editName);
    final MaterialEditText editPassword = (MaterialEditText) register_layout.findViewById(R.id.editPassword);
    final MaterialEditText editPhone = (MaterialEditText) register_layout.findViewById(R.id.editPhone);

    form.setView(register_layout);

    form.setPositiveButton("REGISTER", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int i) {

            dialog.dismiss();

            if(TextUtils.isEmpty(editEmail.getText().toString())){
                Snackbar.make(baseLayout,"Please enter email", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }

            if(TextUtils.isEmpty(editPassword.getText().toString())){
                Snackbar.make(baseLayout,"Please enter password", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }

            if(TextUtils.isEmpty(editName.getText().toString())){
                Snackbar.make(baseLayout,"Please enter name", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }

            if(TextUtils.isEmpty(editPhone.getText().toString())){
                Snackbar.make(baseLayout,"Please enter phone number", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }
        }
    });



    form.setNegativeButton("CANCEL", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });

    AlertDialog build = form.create();
    build.show();

}
```

Any clues?

Answer (score 0):

override positive button from your "build":

```
AlertDialog build = form.create();
```

to:

```
build.getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            //do something...

            build.dismiss();
        }
    });
```